# Home outdoor cooking apparatus for high heat cooking (wok, stir fry)

Tags: wok

I am a chef over in Western Australia and love to cook outdoors in my spare time as we certainly have the weather for it. For Asian cooking (stir fried, in a wok) I'm looking for equipment, but there seems to be no proper market in this field for home use.

There are what is call the [Rambo burners](https://www.auscrown.com.au/products/category/commercial-high-pressure-burners) which seem excellent , but they do not have a proper housing kit for stylish outdoor entertainment.

[Asian charcoal cookers](http://www.bbq-brethren.com/forum/showthread.php?t=155104) look good but are not available for purchase here.

Is there a home outdoor cooking apparatus capable of high heat cooking (specifically for wok cooking) which is perfect for backyard entertaining??

Comment: Alton Brown suggests a traditional american solution: a big fat GRILL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's available in Australia, but in the US they market high-output outdoor burners for deep-frying turkeys. [This one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LTBH2UO) is marketed as 200,000 BTU, twice the output of the ones often used in Chinese restaurants. ([This $1,000 restaurant wok](https://www.centralrestaurant.com/Oriental-Gas-Fired-Wok-Range-c181p3613.html?st-t=google_shopping_490-039-LP&gclid=CjwKCAjwzMbLBRBzEiwAfFz4gdKNG9GY_i_vxQDINa15hXhtnUSc4PfaZaCdwdKYXxXRtriSAXzP_xoCVC0QAvD_BwE) is marketed as 90,000 BTU.)

Most outdoor turkey fryers are marketed as 60,000 BTU, which will probably work reasonably well. They are decidedly *not* to be used indoors; YouTube has many videos of people setting their houses on fire.

Getting one in Australia may be a challenge, but they're very common in the US, and many kitchen stores and (oddly) hardware stores. I imagine you could have one shipped, though I'd verify that your propane tanks are compatible.

Comment: I'd bet they have something similar... we use ours for home brew so the op might consider seeing if there's a brewing store around.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.nationalhomebrew.com.au/beer/brewing-equipment-pots-and-hardware/other-propane-burner-and-stand). Not quite the same but definitely plenty of BTUs.

Comment: Lots of BTUs. It's rated for 150L (40 gallons) of beer. That's a whole lotta beer for home brewing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Australian as well and almost wondering if being a professional chef you're discounting some wok burners that have a lower heat output than professional units but work well for home cooking. I use the side burner on a gas BBQ and just checked and it's rated for 15,000 BTU. I use it along with a traditional Chinese wok that's made of fairly thin cast iron and get the following sort of results:

- For shallow / deep frying I leave it turned up for a couple of minutes to warm the oil (which I guess in a professional environment isn't desirable) but after that leave it set at about 1/3 and it keeps the oil at around 180C.
- For quickly searing I leave it on high temperature lightly oiled and after a few minutes add meat and while I've never measured the temperature I guess it's around 250C or more and it takes peanut oil past the smoke point.

If you're open to waiting a few minutes then apart from getting a gas BBQ with a side-burner there's also a lot of things available here quite cheaply like a [Primus Wok Cooker - Double Burner](http://www.raysoutdoors.com.au/Product/Primus-Wok-Cooker-Double-Burner/292579). You could place that on top of one the modular cabinets made for outdoor cooking and put the gas bottle inside.